# Is the matrix induced L1-norm greater than the induced L2-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, norms, operator-norms

For $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and the induced norms:

$$
\| A \|_1 = \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}
$$
$$
\| A \|_2 = \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
$$

... where:

$$
\|x\|_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|
$$

$$
\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2}
$$

... does the following inequality hold in general?

$$
\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_1
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity I will write $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{p\to r}$ for the $\ell_p$-to-$\ell_r$-norm. Note that in general, $\lVert A\rVert_{1\to r} = \max_{1\leq j\leq n} \lVert (Ae_j)\rVert_r$.

Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose top row has $1$ in every entry, and all other entries of the matrix are $0$. Then by the remark above, $\lVert A\rVert_{1\to 1} =1$. On the other hand,

$$ \lVert A\rVert_{2\to 2} \geq \lVert A^* \rVert_{2\to 2} \geq \lVert A^*e_1\rVert_2 = \sqrt{n} $$

giving a counterexample to your question. (In fact this lower bound is an equality, although this is not needed to answer the question.)

Comment: One point about induced norms on matrices, told me by Kahan  decades ago: if we have two distinct induced norms,  taking the maximum of those creates a new function on matrices with some nice properties, but it cannot be an induced norm itself. Oh: so no induced norm can dominate another.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add the following intuitive explanation of the phenomenon that is at work here: the problem is that a given norm on a vector space influences the induced norm (i.e., the operator norm, as my inner functional analyst wants to say) of an operator $A$ in two ways: in the expression $\|Ax\|$ over which we take a surpremum, and in the condition $\|x\| \le 1$ for taking the supremum. If you increase the norm on the vector space, the first point "wants" to increase the induced norm of $A$, while the second point "wants" to decrease it.

Comment: In fact the counterexample saturates the true bound I have added.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly holds for all matrices where $|a_{ij}|=|a_{ji}|$ (meaning both symmetric and skew-symmetric matruces, among otbers). It is reported [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484779/matrix-norm-bounds) that

$||A||_2^2\le||A||_1||A||_\infty,$

and where the condition above is satisfied $||A||_1=||A||_\infty$.

---

For *all* $n×n$ matrices we always have

$||A||_1\le n||A||_\infty$

$||A||_\infty\le n||A||_1$

and so the bound given above implies

$||A||_2\le\sqrt{n}||A||_1$

$||A||_2\le\sqrt{n}||A||_\infty.$

Comment: Comment just for other readers (apologies if you know this already Oscar): the inequality you mention is a special case of Riesz-Thorin interpolation with $\ell_2^n$ as the halfway-point between $\ell_1^n$ and $\ell_\infty^n$.